# Excel VBA to set axis labels

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel, something like this:

```
        sprint1    sprint2    sprint3
data1      5          6          7
data2      3          7          1
data3      1          7          9
```

I have this code:

```
Public Sub CreateChart(name As String, rng As Range)
    Dim cht As Object
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2
    cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    cht.chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    cht.chart.HasTitle = True
    cht.chart.ChartTitle.Text = name
End Sub
```

I get a chart with the series correctly labeled (data1, data2, data3) in the legend and numbers labeling the y-axis as I expected. However the x-axis is labeled 0-10, it's not using the header row of the data (sprint1, sprint2, sprint3) as x-axis labels. What VBA magic do I need to invoke for this?

I thought it was something like:

```
cht.chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryNames = some_range
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: *"Magic"* Macro recorder did not help to figure out the code?

Comment: `xlXYScatterLines` requires  `x` and `y` values, which is your `x` values? Is the the first row, `data1`?

Comment: There are 3 series of data: data1, data2, and data3. There are 3 x-values each, one for sprint1, sprint2, and sprint3. I would expect the legend to label the 3 series as data1, data2, and data3 - which it does. It plots the 3 series on the graph fine. The y-axis is numbers. But I would expect the x-axis to be labeled per the column headers sprint1, sprint2, and sprint3, but instead it's just numbers.

Comment: Now I understand what you were asking, and I see you found the solution I was going to suggest. XY Scatter plots require numeric x-axis, but line charts have categories for x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of the problem is that the chart type does not support this. I changed this line of code:

```
cht.chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
```

to this:

```
cht.chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
```

and now it works, the x-axis labels are the sprint names.